# Can´t use multiple bootstrap modals in django template

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Im writing a template view on which i need to open several different modals - always just one at a time. This template has tabs and the trigger buttons for the modals are between the tab navigations and the tab content. I used multiple modals like this before with exactly the same code in a different view except the tab navigation and it works like supposed. But in this template my modal divs get nested together so the data-toggle wont work. Im sure i missed something little but i cant figure out what

[image: Thats the nested divs]

I tried to put the modal at the end of the included html (noteTable.html)to separate the modals, but this breaks my tab navigation - all content from every tab is shown in each tab then

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newKNAModal">Kosten-Nutzen-Analyse</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newNote"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Neue Notiz</button>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="details" role="tabpanel">
       {% include 'detailForm.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="notes" role="tabpanel">
       {% include 'noteTable.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="dokumente" role="tabpanel">
       {% include 'documentTable.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- New KNA Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="newKNAModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% include 'newKNA.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- New Notes Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="newNote" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% include 'newNote.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect that if i click the button the right Modal opens. But just the first one opens, the second one has just the fade animation but no html is shown

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out what the mistake was. It was not in my code from the template nor was it the initiation of the modals. It was simply a missing `</div>` in one of my modal contents - the one i include at `{% include 'newKNA.html' %}`. That way the browser nested all the `<div>` inside the first one.